# How does Dart's bindSecure function find SSL certificates?

Tags: ssl, dart, dart-io

So I'm writing a server in Dart and want to enable SSL. The `bindSecure` function is supposed to accomplish that for me, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually refer to the certificate. Let's say that I write the function like so:

```dart
HttpServer.bindSecure('localhost', 3000, 'my_cert.pem').then((HttpServer server) {
  ... do stuff with server ...
});
```

I've tried doing this with the `.pem` file in the same directory as the server file, but to no avail. I always get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: CertificateException: Cannot find server certificate by nickname: my_cert.pem
```

I've also tried using `./my_cert.pem`, linking from the root directory of the overall project, etc., but so far to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

in this post [Secure Sockets and Servers with Dart 1.0](http://jamesslocum.com/post/70003236123) it is used like

```dart
'CN=my_cert'
```

where `my_cert` is the common name you used when you created the certificate.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. But the problem could very well be in the certificate generation process.